# JSON exception: Value of type string cannot be converted to JSON Object?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am getting this error when trying to run the following code, A simple sign in/up `Android` activity that links to a `PHP` script and `MYSQL` database, hosted on `00WebHost`.

How do I solve this? note: this is stopping the DB being populated.

**When submit button clicked:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {


                // get The User name and Password
                String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();

                  // WebServer Request URL
                String serverURL = "http://ry.net16.net/login_web_service.php?username=" + userName + "&password=" + password;

                // Use AsyncTask execute Method To Prevent ANR Problem
                new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);

                Log.d("trace url", "URL TRACE");

                {

                }

                {

                }
            }
        });
```

**LongOperation class:**

```
 private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        // Required initialization

        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Content;
        private String Error = null;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(SignInActivity.this);
        String data =""; 
        int sizeData = 0;  


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            //Start Progress Dialog (Message)

            Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            Dialog.show();



        }

        // Call after onPreExecute method
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

            /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
            BufferedReader reader=null;

                 // Send data 
                try
                { 

                   // Defined URL  where to send data
                   URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                  // Send POST data request

                  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
                  conn.setDoOutput(true); 
                  OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
                  wr.write( data ); 
                  wr.flush(); 

                  // Get the server response 

                  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                  String line = null;

                    // Read Server Response
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                               // Append server response in string
                               sb.append(line + "");
                        }

                    // Append Server Response To Content String 
                   Content = sb.toString();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Error = ex.getMessage();
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {

                        reader.close();
                    }

                    catch(Exception ex) {}
                }

            /*****************************************************/
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            // Close progress dialog
            Dialog.dismiss();

            if (Error != null) {


               // uiUpdate.setText("Output : "+Error);

            } else {

                // Show Response Json On Screen (activity)
              //  uiUpdate.setText( Content );

             /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/

                String OutputData = "";
                JSONObject jsonResponse;

                try {

                     /****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
                     jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);

                     String result = jsonResponse.get("result").toString();

                     if (result.equals("true"))
                        {
                            SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
                            Editor editor = pref.edit();                     

                            /**************** Storing data as KEY/VALUE pair *******************/

                            editor.putBoolean("loggedIn", true);           // Saving boolean - true/false


                            // Save the changes in SharedPreferences
                            editor.commit(); // commit changes                              

                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                             Intent i = new Intent(SignInActivity.this ,  MainActivity.class);
                             startActivity(i);


                        }
                     else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match. Please Sign Up if you are new. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                    }
                 /****************** End Parse Response JSON Data *************/    

                  catch (JSONException e) {

                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }


             }
        }

    }
```

**Corresponding PHP script: (log in details excluded**

```
 <?php


    // To check if passed parameters are present or not.
    if(isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password']))
    {

//NOTE THESE ARE INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK FOR SECURITY
    $mysql_host = "";
    $mysql_database = "";
    $mysql_user = "";
    $mysql_password = "";

    // Provide host ip, mysql user name, password to make connection
     $con = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);

    // Provide database name.
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database);


    // Fetching the passed parameters 
        $username=$_GET['username'];

        $password=$_GET['password'];

        $flag="false";

    // Checking if parameters are not null
        if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
        {


            $sql="select * from `Login` where `UserName`='$username' and `Password`='$password' ";


            $result=mysql_query($sql);

            if($result)
            {
                // count number of rows returned .
                $count= mysql_num_rows($result);
                if($count > 0)
                {
                    $flag="true"; //result true 

                }               

            }
                    // closing connection
                       mysql_close($con);
            //returning json response 
            echo json_encode(array("result"=>$flag));
        }



    }

    ?>
```

**Full Logcat Error:**

```
08-15 18:24:59.117: W/System.err(29260): org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-15 18:24:59.117: W/System.err(29260):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
08-15 18:24:59.117: W/System.err(29260):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
08-15 18:24:59.117: W/System.err(29260):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
08-15 18:24:59.117: W/System.err(29260):    at com.hmkcode.android.sign.SignUpActivity$LongOperation.onPostExecute(SignUpActivity.java:160)
08-15 18:24:59.117: W/System.err(29260):    at com.hmkcode.android.sign.SignUpActivity$LongOperation.onPostExecute(SignUpActivity.java:1)
08-15 18:24:59.117: W/System.err(29260):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
08-15 18:24:59.117: W/System.err(29260):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-15 18:24:59.117: W/System.err(29260):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
08-15 18:24:59.117: W/System.err(29260):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-15 18:24:59.127: W/System.err(29260):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-15 18:24:59.127: W/System.err(29260):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
08-15 18:24:59.127: W/System.err(29260):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 18:24:59.127: W/System.err(29260):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-15 18:24:59.127: W/System.err(29260):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-15 18:24:59.127: W/System.err(29260):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-15 18:24:59.127: W/System.err(29260):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 18:24:59.147: E/ViewRootImpl(29260): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

**EDIT:
JSON PARSER CLASS:**

Below is the JSON parser class related the application.

```
package com.hmkcode.android.sign;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

    public class JSONParser {

        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {

        }

        public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();           

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;

        }
    }
```

Comment: your string is not a valid json. check the server response

Comment: can you post your json?

Comment: Can you post some user and pwd?

Comment: The Json is within the LongOperation class

Comment: my json parser class is also shown in edit

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
String serverURL = "http://ry.net16.net/login_web_service.php?username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName) + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password);
```

Comment: This has not solved the issue, im gettin the same erros

Comment: The JSON is within the LongOperation class?

Comment: sorry I am quite new to using JSON and PHP

Comment: your php has 6 error. Fix it. Select: "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE UserName='".$username."' AND Password='".$password."' "

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the non JSON string

What does

> http://ry.net16.net/login_web_service.php?username=" + userName + "&password=" + password

give in browser? If this is not an JSON output then you need to check why the URL is not giving you JSON formatted text.

Please post the output of the URL.

Comment: The output of the URL is blank, it does not give anything

Comment: Ok so the problem is with your PHP piece, it should return you the formatted response. Try debugging  //returning json response 
            echo json_encode(array("result"=>$flag));

Comment: Could this be an issue with the connection to my MYSQL datbase from the script?

Comment: yes could be so to debug try json_encode(array("Apple", "Banana", "Pear")); instead to check if there is an issue with result.

Comment: Thanks, How would i know that ry.net16.net/login_web_service.php? is the correct address for the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You have serious issues with that PHP script, I just opened that URL, in browser and saw whole lot of errors. So in short, the PHP script is not returning any `JSON` it is giving you `HTML` which is nothing but all PHP warnings...

Comment: @codeme2020, first you need to fix your PHP, it is broken as of now.

Comment: OK, unfortunately I am not too sure about PHP, this is my first attempt at using it. How can I fix it?

Comment: There is some issue with your MySQL username/password. Your script is unable to connect to database

Comment: Yeah, would this be to do with the webhost I am using? Im almost sure the script and android activity are ok

Comment: It seems like you are new to both PHP and Android. I would request you to do some reading on both before trying to integrate them together

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you are not getting an actual JSON encoded response. As mentioned in other answers, you are getting errors trying to connect to the database.:

`Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host 'srv36.000webhost.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/a5369581/public_html/login_web_service.php on line 14`

You'll need to ensure that the `$mysql_user` has the appropriate permissions set on the MySQL database. If the php script is on the 000webhost server, which also hosts your sql server, then you should be able to use the login credentials provided on the 000webhost dashboard in members area.

Comment: Thanks, How would i know that http://ry.net16.net/login_web_service.php? is the correct address for the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, and its quite embarrassing, basically i was not using the correct `log-in` details for the `MYSQL Database.`